# Split One Column to Multiple Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split one [current column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6TsQ.jpg) into 3 columns. In screenshot we see the builder column, which need to be split in 3 more column such as b.name , city and country. So I use str.split() method in python to split the column which give me good result for 2 column `ownerName = df['owner_name'] df[["ownername", "owner_country"]] = df["owner_name"].str.split("-", expand=True)`

But when it come to three columns `ownerName = df['owner_name'] df[["ownername", "city", "owner_country"]] = df["owner_name"].str.split("," ,"-", expand=True)`, where I use 2 delimiter ',' and '-' it give me this error:

> File "C:\Users....\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3160, in **setitem**
> self._setitem_array(key, value)
> File "C:\Users....\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3189, in _setitem_array
> raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
> ValueError: **Columns must be same length as key**

whats best solution for 2 delimiter ',' and '-',   Also there is some empty rows too.

Comment: Use a regex delimiter: `"[,-]"`

Comment: so replace this  ("-", "," , expand=True)  with  (["-", ","] , expand=True)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exact input is unclear, but assuming the sample input kindly provided by @ArchAngelPwn, you could use `str.split` with a regex:

```
names = ['Builder_Name', 'City_Name', 'Country']
out = (df['Column1']
 .str.split(r'\s*[,-]\s*', expand=True)  # split on "," or "-" with optional spaces
 .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(names))) # rename 0/1/2 with names in order
)
```

output:

```
   Builder_Name City_Name  Country
0  Builder Name      City  Country
```

Comment: input is like builder name = Alex - new york ,USA . so result i want to split this name into name column, city and country coulmns

Comment: I replaced ['Column1'] with [builder_name] so it run but didn't give me any result. Previous one i mentioned in question give me result but just for ','.

Comment: is there any solution for this ? error: line 93, in <module>
    df[["Builder_name", "builder_city", "builder_country"]] = df["builder"].str.split(r', |- |\*|\n', expand=True) also line 3160, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_array(key, value).... line 3189, in _setitem_array
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: Try to run only the right part of the `=`? What is the output? Do you have as many columns as on the left (3)?

Comment: yeah I have more then 200000 rows in on column, when i try it on just some data work but when apply to all at same time its give me that error.

Comment: so, how many columns has your split?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine some rows if you feel like you need to, but this was a possible options and should be pretty readable for most developers included in the projects

```
data = {
    'Column1' : ['Builder Name - City, Country']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Builder_Name'] = df['Column1'].apply(lambda x : x.split('-')[0])
df['City_Name'] = df['Column1'].apply(lambda x : x.split('-')[1:])
df['City_Name'] = df['City_Name'][0]
df['City_Name'] = df['City_Name'].apply(lambda x : x.split()[0])
df['City_Name'] = df['City_Name'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(',', ''))
df['Country'] = df['Column1'].apply(lambda x : x.split(',')[1])
df = df[['Builder_Name', 'City_Name', 'Country']]
df
```

Comment: This will be highly inefficient (especially since you can use concise pandas code for a vectorial approach)

Comment: Then please share your version in a post so that others may learn. This is simply the way that I would do it. Also remember that while people are helping not everyone is as experienced as everyone else so not all code will be as optimized as others based on experience. A post that explains a more optimal way is the most efficient way to help improve not only those posting questions as well as those posting answers.

Comment: Sure, I added an answer, let me know if you have questions ;)

Comment: Thank you, I really enjoy studying your posts! I'm not nearly as skilled as your post so I know your super talented, please remember than when your out there rocking with your amazing optimized posts and comments! Please keep up the good work! (also if you wanted to add some comments to your posts that would be cool to because sometimes I read them and they work, but I have no idea what they are actually doing haha)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in questions there is 2 delimiter "-" and ",". for one we simply use *str.split("-", expand=True)* and for 2 different delimiter we can use same code with addition of small code such as **column1 = name-city name ,country (Owner = SANTIERUL NAVAL CONSTANTA - CONSTANTZA, ROMANIA)** code will be write as `ownerName = df['owner_name'] df[["Owner_name", "City_Name", "owner_country"]] = df["owner_name"].str.split(r', |- |\*|\n', expand=True)`
[image: result]